# Modify directory permissions for "others" in RPM

Tags: package-management, permissions, tomcat, rpm

How to set write permissions for "others" in a .spec file for RPM
As far as I understand "others" is a flag used for all users that are not the owner.

I am trying to set the permissions in % attr section of .spec file

**%files**

**%defattr(-,root,root)**

**%attr(-,others,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/conf**

**%attr(-,others,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/logs**

**%attr(-,others,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/temp**

**%attr(-,others,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/webapps**

**%attr(-,others,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/work**

and when I install the RPM it tells me that *user others does not exist - using root*

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I understand "others" is a flag used for all users that are not the owner.

No. "Others" permission is the last bit in `chmod`, e.g. permissions 064**4** for a file allow reading of the file by anybody who is neither member of the group owner of the file, neither the owner of the file.

What actual system users are "others" will depend on `chown` permissions (ownership).

For example, the file is owned (`chown`ed`) as` root:root`. It means` root`user is the owner, and`root`group is the group owner. So others are any users who are neither`root`user, nor members of`root` group.

The `%attr` macro has this signature:

```
%attr(<mode>, <user>, <group>) <file>
```

So when you specify:

```
%attr(-,others,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/conf
```

This will of course not work unless there is an actual `others` user in the system.

Simply use the first argument to a macro which is `mode` (or, simply, `chmod` of the files in question). Example:

```
%attr(0644,root,root) /opt/platform3pp/P3PPapache-tomcat-9.0.14-1.1/conf
```

The result will be the file will be owned by `root:root` and chmod will be `0644`, which, accounting for the last bit (others), will allow all users to read the file.